# When is it necessary to sign a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, assembly-signing, snk

Visual Studio offers the option of signing `.NET` assemblies with a `.SNK` key.

In what situations would it be necessary to sign an assembly?

What effect does signing an assembly have on warning messages about "Unknown Publisher"?

Comment: Did you [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=When+is+it+necessary+to+sign+a+.NET+assembly%3F) this? I mean there are very good [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975723/c-why-sign-an-assembly) on SO already. I'm surprised to see this from someone with more gold badges than myself.

Comment: This is a good concise answer to the question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/377638/327528

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: you do have a fair few more points than me.

Comment: I think my search feature works the same as yours, though. (That was my point.)

Answer (score 1):

When whoever is using your assembly needs to know it came from you and a third party didn't sneak in and replace your application with their own. I believe you also need to sign an assembly if you wish to add it to the GAC.